# How to send 'ACCT' to FTPs with PHP+CURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I successfully log into FTP server as this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://192.168.X.X');    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');

print_r(curl_exec($ch));    
print_r(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

But when it come to FTPs, I got this:

> ACCT requested but none available

How do I send ACCT command to build the connection? Got no luck on

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'ACCT ACNT');
```

Comment: If you not need use curl, you can consider use [ftp](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) lib of php.

Comment: I am sure that the FTP server request ACCT command. I can't find ways to send ACCT command in ftp_connect() or ftp_login() either. And because it's FTPS, it's better to go with curl. I can't use ftp_ssl_connect() on Windows.